# DB > PowerBI > Web (VARIABLE)

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

How would you solve this?

Importing table from DB

| COLUMN1 | COLUMN2 | COLUMN3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Audi | BMW | Daewoo |
| Honda | Lexus | Mazda |
| Toyota | Suzuki | Volvo |

Then pick COLUMN2 and run foreach with variable like this for each group:
[www.stackoverflow.com/group=[VARIABLE]?users=all](http://www.stackoverflow.com/group=%5BVARIABLE%5D?users=all) to get all members from BMW, Lexus, Suzuki groups and create new table like this:

| BMW | Lexus | Suzuki |
| --- | --- | --- |
| James | David | George |
| Robert | Charles | Joseph |
| Edward | William | Brian |

Comment: Please provide full sample input data and desired output

Comment: Are you looking to make a web request with `[BMW,Lexus,Suzuki]` as a parameter based on COLUMN2? Or make a web request for each row in COLUMN2? The `[ARRAY]` bit is confusing.

Comment: Hello, thats second one. Web request for each row in COLUMN2. Sorry for confusing you.